# After Effects is not changing the preview quality!

Tags: after-effects, preview

[image]I have the preview resolution set to quarter, frame skip set to 5 and yet After Effects is previewing at full resolution constantly. I have tried changing the settings through the sidebar and the bar under the preview.

I have purged the RAM, cache, etc. several times and even re-opening the program does not help.

The preview is indeed set to 'Adaptive resolution'. This is making the preview playback impossible since my footage is 4K.

Answer (score 1):

Quarter of 4K is still 1080. Depending on your rig it still might chug thru playback. I would look into proxies as they are pretty quick to set up and would drastically improve workability.

Comment: I'll second looking into setting up a proxy workflow. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vX18PMX-nS4    (AE) 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6w7RIdACweQ   (Premiere)

Comment: Good point but this was not the case. Even 1080p footage was still being shown at full 1080 instead of being scaled downwards.